# Queryset filters: Q objects and filters auto generation (Django)

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-q

For example I have an a function for generating filters parameters:

```
def get_filters_parameters(name=None, mother_age=None, surname_not=None):
    filters = {}
    if name:
        filters['name'] = name
    if mother_age:
        filters['mother__age'] = mother_age
    # if surname_not:
    #     here we need `~Q(surname = surname_not)` expression
    return **filters

my_filters = get_filters_parameters(name='ululu')
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(**my_filters)
```

I need to use Q objects in my filters parameters for `surname_not` field.
Does anyone knows how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just stick with using Q.

```
def get_filters_parameters(name=None, mother_age=None, surname_not=None):
    filters = Q() 
    if name:
        filters &= Q(name=name) 
    if mother_age:
        filters &= Q(mother__age=mother_age) 
    if surname_not:
        filters &= ~Q(surname=surname_not)
    return filters

my_filters = get_filters_parameters(name='ululu')
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(my_filters)
```